# Cannot read property 'checked' of null in TestCase

Tags: jquery, code-coverage, qunit, testcase, blanket.js

In my JS I have below mentioned code in Initialize function.

```
initialize: function () {

        if (!$("#VisitorIsSelected").is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#VisitorIsSelected").attr('checked', true);
        }
}
```

But when I run below mentioned Test Case via Qunit.js and blanket.js it shows me error :Cannot read property 'checked' of null - {}"

```
test("initialize test", 3, function () {
    $('<input>').appendTo("body");
    $('<select>').appendTo("body");
    $('<input>', { type: "checkbox", checked: true, id: "VisitorIsSelected"}).appendTo("body");
    var result = initialize();
    equal(undefined, result, "passed");

    $('input, select').trigger("blur");    
    ok(true, "blur event called");
    $('input, select').trigger("change");
    ok(true, "change event called");
    $("input").remove();
    $("select").remove();
});
```

What should be the exact test case?

Comment: do `console.log($("#VisitorIsSelected"));` are you getting object on console?

Comment: Your code seems working http://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/5z653w7a/ . Wich version are you using ?

Comment: @QuentinRoger I am using "jquery 1.4.1.js".